# como extrair arquivos zip em c# para uma pasta onde o sistema está instalado

Tags: c#, .net, xml, arquivo-zip

Como extrair arquivos zip em [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) para uma pasta onde o sistema está instalado?

```
using System;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Windows;
using System.Xml;

namespace TestXml
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string Dir2 = @"c:\IASD\Cantina Escolar\";
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("http://www.meusite.com/arquivoXML.xml");

            XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Application/Version");
            XmlNode node1 = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Application/ZipFile");
            string version = node.InnerText;
            string zipfile = node1.InnerText;

            string End = "http://www.meusite.com/";

            string Arq = version;
            string file = zipfile;

            string Arquivo = String.Concat(End, zipfile);
            string Arquivo2 = String.Concat(@"c:\IASD\Cantina Escolar\",zipfile); 

            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.DownloadFile(Arquivo, @"C:\IASD\Cantina Escolar\"+zipfile);

            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(Arquivo2, zipfile);
        }
    }
}
```

A mensagem de erro apresentada é:

> URI formats are not supported.

Então resumindo:

Eu vou no servidor e coloco um zip, que é uma atualização para ser baixada. Manualmente altero o arquivo XML colocando a versão do arquivo, que nada mais é que o nome do arquivo a ser descompactado. O método lê o XML e tem que baixar e descompactar o arquivo zip na pasta de instalação do sistema.

Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Você está fazendo certa confusão, até onde entendi sobre seu problema é que você deseja descompactar um arquivo que estará disponível em uma url online. Acontece que você precisa antes fazer download desse arquivo pro seu disco local, para só então extrair esse arquivo.

Comment: eu faço o download só que ele não vai pra pasta onde eu determinei que fosse. Está indo pra pasta bin\Debug. estou baixando com  WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.DownloadFile(Arquivo,@"c:\pasta\Diretório_onde_descompactar\"+zipfile); Quando ele faz o unzip, está criando uma pasta com o nome do arquivo e não descompactando o arquivo diretamente no diretório que determinei.

Comment: Cola seu código completo, com o download do arquivo.

Comment: não tenho pontuação para responder a própria pergunta e aqui fica inviável.

Comment: Vou ter que fazer outra resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Isto ocorre porque você está esperando que a função de descompactação seja capaz de fazer o download do seu arquivo zip, e não é assim que ela funciona. Primeiro você precisa baixar o arquivo, salvar em algum lugar pra depois abri-lo e descompactá-lo.

O seguinte código deve funcionar:

```
using System;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Windows;
using System.Xml;

namespace TestXml
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var dir = "c:\\pasta\\Diretório_onde_descompactar";

            //abrindo e lendo um arquivo xml para encontrar a versão que está disponível
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("http://www.meusite.com/pasta/arquivoXML.xml");
            XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Application/Version");
            var version = node.InnerText;

            //Aqui eu pego o endereço onde é para descompactar
            // e informo para o ZipFile.ExtractTodirectory
            //passando a concatenação como parâmentro
            var url = "http://meusite.com/pasta/";

            var arq = version;

            var urlArquivo = String.Concat(url, arq, ".zip");

            // Download
            var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlArquivo);            
            var response = webRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            var stream = response.GetResponseStream();

            using (ZipInputStream zipStream = new ZipInputStream(stream))
            {
                ZipEntry currentEntry;
                while ((currentEntry = zipStream.GetNextEntry()) != null)
                {
                    currentEntry.Extract(dir, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: eu faço o download só que ele não vai pra pasta onde eu determinei que fosse. Está indo pra pasta bin\Debug. estou baixando com WebClient webClient = new WebClient(); webClient.DownloadFile(Arquivo,@"c:\pasta\Diretório_onde_descompactar\"+zipfile)‌​; Quando ele faz o unzip, está criando uma pasta com o nome do arquivo e não descompactando o arquivo diretamente no diretório que determinei.

Comment: Você pode atualizar seu código na pergunta para que eu possa ver exatamente o que está sendo executado agora?

Comment: Código atualizado

Answer (score 1):

Após a mudança de código, o problema que ocorre é que o uso de `DownloadFile` está incorreto. `String.Concat` não mapeia o diretório na máquina: apenas monta uma `String` com um nome de diretório.

O correto neste caso é usar `Path.Combine()`.

O código final fica assim:

```
using System;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Xml;

namespace TestXml
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string Dir2 = @"c:\IASD\Cantina Escolar\";
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("http://www.meusite.com/arquivoXML.xml");

            XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Application/Version");
            XmlNode node1 = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Application/ZipFile");
            string version = node.InnerText;
            string zipfile = node1.InnerText;

            string End = "http://www.meusite.com/";

            string Arq = version;
            string file = zipfile;

            string Arquivo = String.Concat(End, zipfile);
            string destino = Path.Combine(@"c:\IASD\Cantina Escolar\" + zipfile);

            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.DownloadFile(Arquivo, destino);

            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(@"c:\IASD\Cantina Escolar\", destino);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Quando eu uso o Server.MapPath preciso importar alguma outra coisa pois está dando o erro: The name 'Server' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Sua aplicação não é Web, certo? Vou atualizar a resposta.

Comment: Com Path.Combine ocorreu o mesmo problema. Ele baixou normalmente, mas descompactou em bin\Debug e criou um diretório com o mesmo nome do arquivo zip.

Comment: Um problema para quem está trabalhando com atualizações de sistema desse tipo é quando o código que é responsável pela atualização está dentro do próprio sistema não sendo possível substituir os arquivos que estão em execução e não podendo rodar os métodos que fazem a atualização sem a aplicação ser iniciada.

Existe alguma rotina de atualização que eu possa aplicar nesse caso que resolveria esse problema?

Agradeço a ajuda.